# Will any js libraries be updating api's with html5 under the hood?

Tags: javascript, libraries, html5, backward-compatibility

So there is a lot of cool stuff in the html5/css3 specs which should be able to replace a lot of the stuff that have been traditionally done with javascript.

Does anyone know if any of the major js libraries (jquery, mootools, extjs, etc) or any newer js libraries are going to be implementing their libraries in such a way that an html5 implementation will be used; but defaults to existing implementation (html4/pre-CSS3/js) when older browsers (IE8/FF3.5 and earlier) are used for backwards compatibility?

Basically, I'm trying to find out if there is a trend in this direction; or if this is kind of a reset point where completely new libraries are being written as opposed to mashups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seriously doubt that anyone one would dump a mature library like jQuery simply because there's a new spec in town. Additionally, since there is no single thing called HTML5 (it's a modular spec) there is no way to predict which parts of it will be implemented (correctly) by which browsers. All of the better JS libraries do capability-based testing for the existence of certain features, and then supply function equivalents for those that are missing.

For production web sites we will have to deal with old/broken browsers for many, many years to come.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the major libaries already do a bit of browser sniffing and capability testing to offload work to the much faster native implementations in browsers where possible. No reason to think this sort of thing won't continue as browsers become much more capable.

2012 Update: jquery 2.0 will not support a number of legacy browsers partially to eliminate lots of sniffing and compensating code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at extjs. They justcame out with extjs 4 and I believe that they're taking advantage of HTML 5 features. They have a new charting package which uses the HTML 5 canvas. They also provide SQLite options. I haven't looked into it much, but if I were you I would do a little bit of research into it.